# can get table_name but not column_name

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

Here is my code

```
 string queryString = "";
            if (table == "") queryString = "select table_name from all_tables";
            else queryString = "SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_columns " +
                               "WHERE table_name = '"+table+"'"; 
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(conexionbase))
                {
                    try
                    {                        
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                            if (connection != null && connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                            {
                                var nuevadataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(queryString, connection);
                                var nuevadataSet = new DataSet();
                                nuevadataAdapter.Fill(nuevadataSet);
                                for (int i = 0; i < nuevadataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                                {
                                  DropDownList2.Items.Add(nuevadataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
                                }
                                connection.Close();
                            }
                            else
                                else DropDownList2.Items.Add("Cant Make a Connection.");
                        }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    else DropDownList2.Items.Add(ex.Message);
                }

            }
```

is the same code for both columns and tables.
When the "column" value is empty it simply shows all table names in the database, and does it just right.
But when the "column" value has a column name, and it makes the connection, it shows a message "OracleConnection.ConnectionString is invalid".

Why it does this i dont know, i can make a connection and show all table_names, but cant get the column names. 
Im using ODAC only dont have access to the database itself, i also tried using "DESCRIBE name_of_table" and it didnt worked.

What is the correct way to ge all the column names in a table? could it be that i dont access to all the columns? its an external DB.

Comment: It *is* possible that you wouldn't get access to all the column names in a table. For example, there are numerous views and synonyms for catalog (system) tables, where users with different permissions can see only selected columns. Reading the column names for a catalog table (or view) from `dba_tab_columns` may reveal more columns than reading from `all_tab_columns`.

Comment: Are you able to access the database directly (with a front-end like SQL Developer, Toad, SQL\*Plus, etc.)? Are you able to execute the query directly, to confirm you get the proper answers? (Or, can you ask someone with access to the DB to run it for you?) The query LOOKS fine to me.

Comment: i dont have any of that, just the platafform im developing and a connection string.

Comment: Can you write a different, much simpler code snippet that just tries to retrieve the column names from all_tab_columns for one table? Does THAT work?

Comment: it didnt worked, i tried that also with many columns, and is not working.

Comment: See my note under my answer - are you passing in the table name in ALL CAPS? That is required in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like this query:

```
string queryString = @"select tb.table_name 
from all_tables tb
left join all_tab_columns  tc 
     on tb.table_name = tc.TABLE_NAME
where
     tc.COLUMN_NAME like '%"+ column + "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to get the result in a single `SELECT` statement (just tested on my Oracle DB, both with empty string, same as NULL in Oracle, and with an actual table name). When I pass in a non-empty string that doesn't match the name of any table in my DB, I get an empty result set. The query still runs perfectly fine, it just returns zero rows as it should.

:var_table is a bind variable; this is where you would insert your variable in your `C#` code.

In all cases, exactly one of the branches of `union all` will be executed (and the other will be discarded by the runtime almost instantaneously).

```
select  table_name from all_tables
  where :var_table is null
union all
select  column_name from all_tab_columns
  where table_name = :var_table;
```

Comment: sorry should i change :var_table to ":mytablename" or to "mytablename" without colon? it didnt worked either way though.

Comment: @proXima - I wouldn't try it with a variable table name, I would try it with a hardcoded table name first. In that case it shouldn't have the colon before it, it should be enclosed in SINGLE quotes (as you had in your code, correctly!) - AND, very important, the table name should be ALL CAPS. Perhaps that's the issue? Unless escaped, table and column names in the system tables are always ALL CAPS. Just pick a table name for a table you know exists in your DB, and try it that way.

Comment: i have the table_names in caps and it doesnt work :c

Answer (score 0):

```
public string get(string tblname)
        {
            string queryString = "";
            if (tblname == "") queryString = "select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";
            else queryString = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  " +
                               "WHERE table_name = '" + tblname + "'";
            return queryString;
        }
```